# Is there a counter to Yorick?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a counter to Yorick on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yorick actually has very little means of escaping, so if he is ganked from early on he can be gimped enough to the point where he is not a large threat.  He becomes incredibly tanky, so make sure you try to get him early.  The later you gank him, the more levels in Omen of Famine he'll have and be much tankier.  Once he's level 3 he also will be able to throw up all 3 ghouls for 15% damage reduction making him very tanky.  Many champions can lane against him by farming his ghouls.  They give no gold, but Tryndamere and Nasus scale better into late game and give them means of gaining strength in lane.  Tryndamere gets it by hitting the ghouls for rage buildup and actually end up healing off of his skills from lifesteal and Bloodlust.  Nasus gets power by building Siphoning Strike charges off of the ghouls.

Source: http://www.lolpro.com/guides/yorick/65-yorick-guide-top-lane/tips-tricks-synergies-and-counters

Comment: Thx great tips I often play jungle so i will remember to gank him to help my top leaner, and thx for some tip one nasus and trynda.

Comment: Your very welcome

Comment: Nasus is a terrible counter, actually. Quite easily, Yorick can zone Nasus, who begins to rely on items for survivability as the game wears on.

Comment: +1 for gank him early. He's strong early because of ghoul harass but once your top has the sustain to deal with it it isn't an issue - two early ganks and they should snowball on him.

Answer (score 4):

**I like to counter Yorick with Cho-Gath, not just because I love Cho but also for these reasons:**

1. *You* can heal of his minions with your passive, they will not do more dmg than your passive heal.
2. *15%* damage reduction? OMNOMNOMNOMNOM!
3. *If* you can get an early gank, you will be way more tankier.
4. *If* you are able to farm and snowball perfectly you will be way ahead of Yorick.

Answer (score 1):

Yorick is annoying due to his ghoul spam. I have seen top lane Warwick deal with him easy because Warwick can sustain himself through Yoricks spam. Also having your jungle keep pressure on him can keep him down a bit as well.

Comment: Thx locks like sustain is the key on winning over him, and to have a ganking jungeler.

Answer (score 1):

I have played Rumble against Yorick and it worked out pretty well. I just torched all the ghouls and they weren't too much of a problem. If you can get an early gank on him with your jungler then you can pretty much dominate the lane with so much damage from your torch and harpoon.

Answer (score 1):

Trundle-

- He heals off Yorick's ghouls
- He can decrease his damage
- Slow him when hes slowed
- Reduce the slow Yorick has
- Awesome 1v1 ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are champs that will completely destroy a yorick 1v1, but many have built in sustain not to be destroyed by his ghouls.  Nasus, builtin lifesteal makes him a strong choice, Trundle's passive, and Chogath passive make it very difficult for Yorick to push them out of lane.  Then when the lane is pushed from the ghoul spamming, just get your jungler to gank and win.

Comment: Good tips thx man, GL HF!

Answer (score 0):

I think Sion is one of the strongest counters to Yorick since he can use Yorick's ghouls against him with Roar of the Slayer (E) by catapulting them into Yorick.

Answer (score -1):

I did extremely well against Yorick as Singed...to my surprise. Turns out all I needed to do was start cloth+5 and get one gank from Maokai to win the lane. Also helped that this Yorick attempted to rush a Manamune like most Yoricks instead of building MR.

Hitting my ult every single time he came in to farm and taking out half his health in one go also helped out a lot.

Comment: You don't have to counter someone to do well against them by snowballing from a jungle gank...